# Создание выборки ключевых слов по признаку delphi 7

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Здравствуйте, есть вот такой код:

```
for i:=0 to memo1.lines.count-1 do
begin
    if memo1.lines[i]=edit1.text then
        memo2.lines.add(memo1.lines[i]);
end;
```

Всё гуд, но у меня есть такой тип текста:

```
memo1
memo55
memo54
memo88
memo7
memo5
```

Как сделать так, что бы когда вводишь `memo` выводило их всех.

Вот еще код:

```
Var SL: TStringList;
    i, s: integer;
    filename: string;
begin
    filename:= '1.txt';
    SL:= TStringList.Create;
    SL.LoadFromFile(filename);
    for i:= 0 to SL.Count-1 do
        if pos(Edit1.text, SL.Strings[i])<>0 then Inc(s);
    Memo1.Lines.Add(IntToStr(s));
end;
```

Но там выводит число строк с таким значением, а не сами строки.
Как сделать что бы выводило сами строки?

Comment: Как объявлены memo1 и memo2?

Comment: есть еще такой код Var SL: TStringList;
    i, s: integer;
    filename: string;
begin
filename:= '1.txt';
SL:= TStringList.Create;
SL.LoadFromFile(filename);
for i:= 0 to SL.Count-1 do
if pos(Edit1.text, SL.Strings[i])<>0 then Inc(s);
Memo1.Lines.Add(IntToStr(s));
end; но там выводит число строк с таким значением а не сами строки как сделать что бы выводило сами строки хелп плис

Comment: Воспользуйтесь пипой [правка](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/638665/edit) и добавте сформатированный код.

Comment: вроде правильно добавил очень нуждаюсь в помощи

Comment: прошу помогите мне

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Первый:

```
   for i:=0 to memo1.lines.count-1 do
   begin
    if (pos(edit1.text, memo1.lines[i])<>0) then
        memo2.lines.add(memo1.lines[i]);
   end;
```

И второй:

```
Var SL: TStringList;
        i: integer;
        filename: string;
    begin
        filename:= '1.txt';
        SL:= TStringList.Create;
        SL.LoadFromFile(filename);
        for i:= 0 to SL.Count-1 do
            if (pos(Edit1.text, SL.Strings[i])<>0) then 
        Memo1.Lines.Add(SL.Strings[i]);
    end;
```

Update:

в глобальные переменные добавь

```
filename:string;
```

потом в обработчик события кнопки для открытия файла

```
if OpenDialog1.Execute then
begin
    filename = OpenDialog1.FileName;
end
```

на обработчик события нажатия кнопки (onButtonClick)

```
SL:= TStringList.Create; 
SL.LoadFromFile(filename); 
for i:= 0 to SL.Count-1 do 
    if (pos(Edit1.text, SL.Strings[i])<>0) then 
       Memo1.Lines.Add(SL.Strings[i]);
```

Comment: большое спасибо очень признателен вам

Comment: а можно как то это адаптировать под opendialog ?

Comment: `Var SL: TStringList;
        i: integer;
        filename: string;
    begin
  if OpenDialog1.Execute then
      filename = OpenDialog1.Filename;
        SL:= TStringList.Create;
        SL.LoadFromFile(filename);
        for i:= 0 to SL.Count-1 do
            if (pos(Edit1.text, SL.Strings[i])<>0) then 
        Memo1.Lines.Add(SL.Strings[i]);
    end;`

Comment: OpenDialog1.Execute then filename = OpenDialog1.Filename;
тревогу бьет из за = что не так?

Comment: сорян, забыл что в delphi присваивание через `:=` 
исправь :)

Comment: ну теперь ошибок нету но что то оно теперь не выводит результаты можно сделать на одну кнопку открытие файла а на другую поиск

Comment: извиняюсь мой косяк всё чётко